# A function that rotates a matrix X degrees clockwise or counter clockwise

Tags: python, rotation, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to write a function, `rotateByX`, that accepts two parameters, a 4x4 matrix and a number that represents the degrees to rotate the matrix. The degrees are 90, 180, 270,360.. and so on. If the entered degree is positive then the matrix rotates to the right clockwise. If it's negative (e.g -90,-180..) then the matrix rotates to the left, counter clockwise. I was able to solve a similar problem, in which I needed only to rotate 90 degrees **clockwise**. I used this funnction in my code here, and also made another function that rotates 90 degrees **counter clockwise**. So I rotate the matrix using those two functions, according to the input of degrees.

##### My code:

```
def rotate90_Counter(m):
    return [[m[j][i] for j in range(len(m))] for i in range(len(m[0])-1,-1,-1)]

def rotateByX(m,X):
    rotations = (X//90)%4
    if X >= 0:
        for p in range(rotations):
            m= rotate90_clockwise(m)
            
    elif X < 0:
        for s in range(rotations):
            m= rotate_90_Counter(m)
            
    return m
        
m = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12],[13,14,15,16]]

rotateByX(m, -90)
```

This is currently working only when the input of degrees, X, is positive. So 90, 180, 270.. it rotates beautifuly. But with negative X it rotates to the right (clockwise) rather than to the left.

Comment: @mkrieger1 for example with `X = -90`, the value of `rotations` is 3, which makes sense. And when `X = 90`, the value of `rotations` is 1. So far so good, however even when `X = -90`, it acts as it is `X = 90` and rotates the matrix only once to the right. `rotate90_Counter` works I tested beforehand.

Comment: @mkrieger1 This is what I'm trying to do for now yes.

Comment: Correction: to rotate by 90 degrees to the left, I rotate 3 times **clockwise**.  My mistake. @mkrieger1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rotateByX` calculates a number `rotations` which is *the number of times to rotate clockwise by 90 degrees* in order to achieve a rotation by `X` degrees clockwise (which is equal to `-X` degrees counterclockwise).

So just always rotate clockwise `rotations` times. Don't rotate counterclockwise ever. Drop the `if X >= 0`/`elif X < 0`, all the relevant information about `X` is already contained in `rotations`.

```
def rotateByX(m, X):
    rotations = (X // 90) % 4

    for p in range(rotations):
        m = rotate90_clockwise(m)
            
    return m
```